# How to prevent grep -f from sorting and removing duplicates

Tags: grep

I am using the function `grep -f inputfile searchfile`
As a result however I get the data sorted and all duplicates are removed. But this is actually not what I want and I cannot find a way to prevent this. Is there a way I get the exact same order as in the inputfile?

I don't understand why grep is doing this because in my memory this should not be happening. What could I do wrong here?

An example:
my inputfile looks like (first few lines shown):

```
Moraceae
Poaceae
Fagaceae
Rosaceae
Betulaceae
Salicaceae
```

My search file looks like (first few lines shown):

```
Acanthaceae 0   1   0   1   1   0   10  0   10  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   0   0   0
Adoxaceae   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Aizoaceae   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   1   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Amaranthaceae   0   1   0   0   7   0   5   0   4   1   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   4   0   0   0
```

The output looks like (first few lines shown):

```
Acanthaceae 0   1   0   1   1   0   10  0   10  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   0   0   0
Aizoaceae   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   1   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Amaranthaceae   0   1   0   0   7   0   5   0   4   1   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   4   0   0   0
Amaryllidaceae  0   1   0   0   6   1   11  0   6   4   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   8   0   0   0
Anacardiaceae   0   1   0   0   0   0   20  0   7   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   10  0   0   0
```

The names are printed in red, meaning that they were matching.But I want to retrieve the exact same order and occurence as my inputfile, starting with "Moraceae". Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Consider showing an example of this behaviour.  Also, you are aware that `inputfile` should contain the regular expressions that you want to look for in `searchfile`?

Comment: My version of grep doesn't do that.

Comment: Good idea, I added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you show (although not immediately apparent from your example, since you don't show the full content of your `inputfile`) is expected. `grep` searches line-wise, meaning that every line of `searchfile` is checked against all patterns in `inputfile` and printed if any of them apply.

What you want to do seems to be a sequential check of `searchfile` against the patterns in `inputfile`, which is only possible in a multi-pass or buffering scenario.

You could write it as a `bash` loop (=multipass approach) or use `awk` (=buffering approach):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{pat[++np]=$0;next}
     {for (i=1;i<=np;i++) {if ($0~pat[i]) buf[i]=buf[i] ? buf[i] ORS $0:$0}}
     END{for (i=1;i<=np;i++) {if (buf[i]) print buf[i]}}' inputfile searchfile
```

This will first read all patterns in `inputfile` into an array `pat`, keeping the order of `inputfile`.

When processing of `inputfile` is finished, it will check every line of `searchfile` if it fits one of the patterns, and store the line grouped by pattern in a buffer array `buf`. In the end, the buffer content is printed, resulting in matched lines printed

- in the order of their matching pattern according to `inputfile`
- and secondary to that in the order they appeared in `searchfile`

Note that while using a dedicated tool like `awk` is usually a more efficient solution than using shell loops, this relies on buffering the relevant text and can become a resource problem if your `inputfile` and/or the amount of matched lines in `searchfile` becomes large.

**Caveat:** In its current form, the program uses full regular expression matching, meaning that the content of `inputfile` must not contain characters special to regular expressions (or if it does, properly escape them). If this is not what you want, and a literal string comparison should be performed instead, change the condition

```
if ($0 ~ pat[i])
```

to either

```
if ($1 == pat[i])
```

if the taxonomic category can **only amount to single-word names** (likely in your example), or

```
if (index($0,pat[i])==1)
```

if the names can contain **multiple space-separated words**.

Comment: Thanks so much AdminBee for the clear explanation, really helpfull. I learnt my lesson and need to try avoiding shell loops.

Comment: @TUnix You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

To preserve duplicates and print in the same order as inputfile, do this:

```
while read -r pattern
do
    grep "$pattern" searchfile
done < inputfile
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation as to why they should try your code? Consider explaining what issue your code solves and how it solves it. Also note that you probably want `IFS= read -r` (in case there are backslashes in the regular expressions or flanking whitespace) and to use `grep -e "$pattern"` (in case a pattern starts with a dash).  An issue with your code is what would happen when several patterns matches a single line in `searchfile`.

Comment: @Kusalananda   Good ideas.  I don't think IFS matters if not splitting the input line.  Also not using `grep -e` since the original  question isn't.

Comment: `IFS` matters in the case that flanking whitespaces on lines in `inputfile` matters. The command in the question does not need `-e` since it doesn't take regular expressions on the command line.  Your code does.